# How can i create a plane out of many meshes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is to extrude a mesh plane.
The plane is in red in the scene view. Each mesh have two triangles.

First i don't understand what is the Res X and Res Z are for. 
What i want to create first is a plane from vertices and triangles in size of 16x16 or any other size by height(Length should be height) and width.
But after i set all the properties to 16 the plane is built from 15x15 meshes not 16x16.

And my main goal is now to extrude the plane. I mean to use OnMouseDown and by a click on the plane to find the closet and neighbours of the vertices from where i clicked on and to extrude this vertice/s. Extrude i mean for example only the z to change the vertices i clicked on position on z only.

Something the same idea like in this image. Marked it in red circle:

[image: Extrude]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class meshPlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int length;
    public int width;
    public int resX;
    public int resZ;

    private MeshFilter meshf;
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateOrigin();
    }

    private void GenerateOrigin()
    {
        // You can change that line to provide another MeshFilter
        meshf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        mesh = new Mesh();
        meshf.mesh = mesh;
        mesh.Clear();

        #region Vertices

        vertices = new Vector3[resX * resZ];
        for (int z = 0; z < resZ; z++)
        {
            // [ -length / 2, length / 2 ]
            float zPos = ((float)z / (resZ - 1) - .5f) * length;
            for (int x = 0; x < resX; x++)
            {
                // [ -width / 2, width / 2 ]
                float xPos = ((float)x / (resX - 1) - .5f) * width;
                vertices[x + z * resX] = new Vector3(xPos, 0f, zPos);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Normales
        Vector3[] normales = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < normales.Length; n++)
            normales[n] = Vector3.up;
        #endregion

        #region UVs     
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        for (int v = 0; v < resZ; v++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < resX; u++)
            {
                uvs[u + v * resX] = new Vector2((float)u / (resX - 1), (float)v / (resZ - 1));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Triangles
        int nbFaces = (resX - 1) * (resZ - 1);
        int[] triangles = new int[nbFaces * 6];
        int t = 0;
        for (int face = 0; face < nbFaces; face++)
        {
            // Retrieve lower left corner from face ind
            int i = face % (resX - 1) + (face / (resZ - 1) * resX);

            triangles[t++] = i + resX;
            triangles[t++] = i + 1;
            triangles[t++] = i;

            triangles[t++] = i + resX;
            triangles[t++] = i + resX + 1;
            triangles[t++] = i + 1;
        }
        #endregion

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.normals = normales;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

[image: Plane]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, can you use some pictures to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I will edit my question and explain.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the plane is built from 15x15 meshes" you mean the plane is built from 15x15 squares. That whole plane is the mesh.

ResX and ResZ are how many points there are in each direction. You get one less square because you need two edges for the first square. You need another two for each square you add, but they can share an edge with the previous one so you need only one more.

To make your mesh clickable you need to add a mesh collider to your gameobject and assign the mesh you generate to it. Then, you can use [the camera class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) to get a ray, put that in a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and if your raycast hits anything you can use [the triangle index](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html) and the triangles array you created to get the three points of the triangle that was hit. In addition you can see which weight in [the barycentric coordinates](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-barycentricCoordinate.html) is bigger to know which exact vertex your click was closest to. And finally, now that you have the exact vertex you can modify its height.